# How to solve $\int \sqrt{a+x^2} dx $, $a>0$?

Tags: calculus, integration

By setting $a+x^2 = t^2$ I can get $2xdx=2dt$ so $dx=dt/\sqrt{t^2-a}$. But such substitutions only lead to iterate integrals of the form
$$
\int \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^2-a}}dt,
$$ 
substituting again $t^2-a=u^2$ we get 
$$
\int udu +\int\frac{2}{\sqrt{u^2+a}}du.
$$
How can I solve the second integral?

Comment: The substitution depends on whether $a>0$ or $a<0$. That is why many tables list $\int\sqrt{x^2-r^2}\,dx$ and $\int\sqrt{x^2+r^2}\,dx$ separately - the idea is that you use the former with negative constant and the latter with positive. You can use the substitutions $x=r\cosh t$ or $x=r\sinh t$ in the respective cases. Then $x^2-r^2=r^2\sinh^2t$ and $x^2+r^2=r^2\cosh^2t$ respectively. Other alternative substitutions exist. The key formula is $\cosh^2t=\sinh^2t+1$, where you may then move the constant to the other side.

Comment: Thank you @JyrkiLahtonen. You are right. I've missed that $a>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set $\sqrt{a+x^2}=x+t$, so $a+x^2=x^2+2tx+t^2$ and
$$
x=\frac{a-t^2}{2t}=\frac{a}{2t}-\frac{t}{2},
\qquad
dx=\left(-\frac{a}{2t^2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)dt=
-\frac{a+t^2}{2t^2}\,dt
$$
Moreover
$$
\sqrt{a+x^2}=\frac{a-t^2}{2t}+t=\frac{a+t^2}{2t}
$$
Hence the integral becomes
$$
-\int\frac{(a+t^2)^2}{4t^3}\,dt=
-\frac{1}{4}\int\left(\frac{a^2}{t^3}+\frac{2a}{t}+t\right)dt
$$
which is elementary.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: substitute $$x=\sqrt{a}\sinh(t)$$

Comment: the simplest way (+1)

Answer (score 2):

You may, alternatively use trigonometric substitution:

In this case, note that $a+ x^2 = (\sqrt a)^2 + x^2$.

The corresponding trig substitution would be to let $x = \sqrt a\tan \theta\;$ so $\;dx = \sqrt a \sec^{2} \theta\,d\theta = \dfrac {\sqrt a}{\cos^2 \theta}\,d\theta$, and you can continue from there.

A good source to you refer when first practicing trig substitution is [this Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution) page dedicated to the use of trig substitution for solving many integrals.

Answer (score 1):

by substitution

$$x=\sqrt { a } \tan { t } $$

Comment: Thank you. By using this substitution I get $\int 2 \sqrt{2}dt / \cos^4(t)$ - how can I proceed from here?

Comment: it should be $\int { \sqrt { a+a\tan ^{ 2 }{ t }  }  } \sqrt { a } \frac { dt }{ \cos ^{ 2 }{ t }  } =a\int { \frac { dt }{ \cos ^{ 3 }{ t }  }  } $ which easy to proceed